# how to check boolean returned value in a condition in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am getting a value **rollNo** from **testA** table and then I am checking the value in query that if the value matches to any row of my another table called **testB**. 
I am adding my query bellow

```
public bool DoesRollNoExists(int rollNo)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rowcount FROM testB WHERE ROLLNO = @rollNo;";

        QueryParamList paramList = new QueryParamList();
        paramList.Add(new QueryParamObj() { ParamName = "ROLLNO ", ParamValue = rollNo, DBType = DbType.Int32 });

        string errorStr = String.Empty;
        DataTable dt = LoadDataTable(sql, paramList, "testB ", ref errorStr);
        return Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Rowcount"].ToString()) > 0 ? true : false;

    }
```

Now my question is how can i check this into condition.

I am adding another source of code with the condition.

```
if (((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["IsActiveStatus"].ToString() == "False")
            {
                bool DoesRollNodExists= ApplicantManager.DoesRollNodExists(rollNo);
                if ( what condition i should put here)
                {
                    item.CssClass = "Green" + " rgRow";
                }
                else
                {
                    item.CssClass = "Red" + " rgRow";
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is "item"? Can you clarify the type of item?

Comment: do you want to check roll no value for each row of data grid?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking "how can i format an if condition when checking a boolean on the return value of a function", it's pretty easy, and there are 2 options:

```
 bool DoesRollNodExists= ApplicantManager.DoesRollNodExists(rollNo);
 if (DoesRollNodExists)
 {
     item.CssClass = "Green" + " rgRow";
 }
 else
 {
     item.CssClass = "Red" + " rgRow";
 }
```

or

```
if (ApplicantManager.DoesRollNodExists(rollNo))
{
     item.CssClass = "Green" + " rgRow";
}
else
{
     item.CssClass = "Red" + " rgRow";
}
```

Either one will work. The first one is better if you want to save that return value to use again later in the function for any reason, but if you don't need to save the return value for later, the second one is fine.